# How do I go between two while loops in a turn-based system?

Tags: python

When I was coding the following for a program:

```
import numpy as np

BB1turn = True
BB2turn = False

class BB1:
  def __init__(BB1, HP, DC):
    BB1.HP = HP
    BB1.DC = DC

class BB2:
  def __init__(BB2, HP, DC):
    BB2.HP = HP
    BB2.DC = DC

BB1 = BB1(6100, 22)
BB2 = BB2(3000, 29)

print("BB1's stats")
print(BB1.HP)
print(BB1.DC)
print("")
print("BB2's stats")
print(BB2.HP)
print(BB2.DC)
print("")
    
def BB1MainGunReload(hit):
  if hit > 0:
    result = hit + BB1MainGunReload(hit - 1)
    print("Your ship has", result, "turn(s) remaining before it can fire again.")
  elif hit == 0:
    values = randint(1, 30, 9)
    print(values)
    hit = np.int_([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    hitpositive = hit[(values >= BB2.DC)]
    print(hitpositive)
    hits = len(hitpositive)
    print(hits, "hit(s)")
    damage = randint(1, 68, hits)
    print(damage)
    a = sum(damage)
    print(a)
    BB2.HP = BB2.HP - a
    print("BB2's HP is now", BB2.HP)
    hit = 3


def BB2MainGunReload(hit):
  if hit > 0:
    result = hit + BB2MainGunReload(hit - 1)
    print("Your ship has", result, "turn(s) remaining before it can fire again.")
  elif hit == 0:
    values = randint(1, 30, 9)
    print(values)
    hit = np.int_([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    hitpositive = hit[(values >= BB1.DC)]
    print(hitpositive)
    hits = len(hitpositive)
    print(hits, "hit(s)")
    damage = randint(1, 68, hits)
    print(damage)
    a = sum(damage)
    print(a)
    BB1.HP = BB1.HP - a
    print("BB1's HP is now", BB1.HP)
    hit = 3



while BB1turn == True:
  print("")
  print("BB1's turn.")
  BB1MainGunReload(3)
  BB1turn = False
  BB2turn = True

while BB2turn == True:
  print("")
  print("BB2's turn.")
  BB2MainGunReload(3)
  BB2turn = False
  BB1turn = True
```

I can't seem to fix the code in a way so that each while loop will take 'turns' with respect to a reload system. I suspect that it has to do with how I input a '3' when I call for the function, but that's all I can figure out. When I put in anything other than a '0', this occurs in the terminal:

```
BB1's stats
6100
22

BB2's stats
3000
29


BB1's turn.
[17 17 29  8 14 10  3  3  8]
[1]
1 hit(s)
[49]
49
BB2's HP is now 2951
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
    BB1MainGunReload(3)
  File "main.py", line 31, in BB1MainGunReload
    result = hit + BB1MainGunReload(hit - 1)
  File "main.py", line 31, in BB1MainGunReload
    result = hit + BB1MainGunReload(hit - 1)
  File "main.py", line 31, in BB1MainGunReload
    result = hit + BB1MainGunReload(hit - 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

When I instead put in a 0 for both of them, the output is as follows:

```
BB1's stats
6100
22

BB2's stats
3000
29


BB1's turn.
[ 7  4  7 19  6 11 10 16 13]
[]
0 hit(s)
[]
0
BB2's HP is now 3000

BB2's turn.
[14  1  3 29  8 21 16 14  4]
[1]
1 hit(s)
[52]
52
BB1's HP is now 6048
```

The program seems to be working as intended, but the while loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setup to only enter each while loop once. You probably want to use a single while loop and then call both players' turns from there.

```
while True:
    if BB1turn:
        print("")
        print("BB1's turn.")
        BB1MainGunReload(3)
        BB1turn = False
        BB2turn = True

    if BB2turn:
        print("")
        print("BB2's turn.")
        BB2MainGunReload(3)
        BB2turn = False
        BB1turn = True
```

I suggest you add some kind of user prompt like `input()` in the loop to avoid flooding the console.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the taking-turns part, the problem with this:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

for input other than `0` is with this bit here:

```
def BB1MainGunReload(hit):
  if hit > 0:
    result = hit + BB1MainGunReload(hit - 1)
```

If `hit` > `0` you're immediately recursively calling `BB1MainGunReload` with `hit -1` until `hit` is `1`. At that point, you're calculating:

```
result = 1 + BB1MainGunReload(1 - 1)
```

or, in actuality:

```
result = 1 + None
```

because when `hit` is `0`, `BB1MainGunReload` returns `None`, because there's no explicit `return` statement.

You're going to want to either return a value, or modify the behavior when `hit` > `0`.